# custom sorting in Ag-grid use Justpy

Tags: python, ag-grid, justpy

I wanna custom sorting ag-grid use justpy. But when I add 'comparator' to columnDefs and run code =>> It not run. It notify l.column.getColDef(...).comparator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sDwgb.png)

can anyone help me

```
import justpy as jp

grid_options = {
    'getDataPath': '''function(data) { return data.orgHierarchy; }''',
    'treeData': True,
    'defaultColDef': {
        'filter': True,
        'sortable': True,
        'resizable': True,
    },
    'columnDefs': [
        {'headerName': "job title", 'field': "jobTitle"},
        {'headerName': "employment type", 
         'field': "employmentType", 
        'comparator': '''function(valueA, valueB) {
            console.log('valuea', valueA)
                if (valueA == valueB) return 0;
                return (valueA > valueB) ? 1 : -1;
        }'''
        },
    ],
    'rowData' : [
        {'orgHierarchy': ['Erica'], 'jobTitle': "CEO", 'employmentType': "1"},
        {'orgHierarchy': ['Erica', 'Malcolm'], 'jobTitle': "VP", 'employmentType': "2"},
        {'orgHierarchy': ['Erica', 'Bob'], 'jobTitle': "SVP", 'employmentType': "3"},
        {'orgHierarchy': ['Erica', 'Bob', 'jo'], 'jobTitle': "eVP", 'employmentType': "4"}
    ]
}

def grid_test():
    wp = jp.WebPage()
    grid = jp.AgGrid(a=wp, options=grid_options)
    print(grid)
    grid.evaluate = ['getDataPath']
    return wp

jp.justpy(grid_test)
```

Comment: looks like there is an image missing ...